# Blender fold cloth/paper/rubber

Tags: animation, rigging

Any ideas/concepts/methods to fold a mesh in a zigzag shape?
My idea is too make it folding, somehow like a falling cloth but in a more clean? controllable zigzag shape.
I need this work in animation.

Created an animation by playing with shape keys (as in picture), but the animation looks stiff.

thanks.
I know, horrible grammar, peace!
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up with animating the curve using empty but in a reverse way. This mean I pose the curve in zigzag shape first then animate it to straighten shape.

[image]
[image]